# Flutter error when wrapping a Positioned widget inside Stack and Column (A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a use case where I have to use `Stack` and `Positioned` to make some overlapping widgets. But I also have to wrap that inside a `Column`. When I do that then I get an error

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
```

A minimal example showing the issue:

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Example"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(children: [
              cardWidget(),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget cardWidget() {
    return Positioned(
      left: 10.0,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I remove `left: 10` then it works fine but thats not what I want.

The full error message (which I don't really understand):

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Positioned(left: 10.0) wants to apply ParentData of type StackParentData to a
RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type FlexParentData.
Usually, this means that the Positioned widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically,
Positioned widgets are placed directly inside Stack widgets.
The offending Positioned is currently placed inside a Column widget.
The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Semantics ← Card ← Positioned ← Column ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ←
LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← ⋯
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to wrap my `Stack` with `Expanded`. Not sure why.

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Example"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Stack(
                children: [0, 1, 2, 3].map((e) => cardWidget(e)).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget cardWidget(int index) {
    return Positioned(
      left: index * 10.0,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 10,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue with this solution is that it won't center my cards (neither horizontal or vertical). How is that achieved?

Comment: You can also wrap the `Stack` with `ConstrainedBox`.

Comment: yeah I think I'd need something like that. However; is it possible to make the box fit the size of the Stack widget (card widget)?

Comment: In that case you'll need to use `Expanded` or `Flexible`.

Comment: Yeah except it takes up all the space then. How do I then align my widget inside the Expanded? I'll add a picture to show the issue

Comment: That's how `Expanded` works. Use `Flexible` if you don't want to force the widget to take up all the space.

Comment: sorry for all these questions (obviously new kid in the flutter community) but I've edited my own suggested solution above. But the issue is that I can't center my stacked cards.

Comment: Set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` for the `Column` widget, it'll center the stack vertically. Since you're using `Positioned` with `left` parameter provided, you can't center the items horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Flutter docs, for the Column class.

*One common reason for this to happen is that the Column has been placed in another Column (without using Expanded or Flexible around the inner nested Column). When a Column lays out its non-flex children (those that have neither Expanded or Flexible around them), it gives them unbounded constraints so that they can determine their own dimensions (passing unbounded constraints usually signals to the child that it should shrink-wrap its contents). The solution in this case is typically to just wrap the inner column in an Expanded to indicate that it should take the remaining space of the outer column, rather than being allowed to take any amount of room it desires.*

This is enough to understand what the problem is

The **Column** is giving the Stack unbounded constraints, due to which you're getting overflow error.

Putting it inside an **Expanded** widget however, solves it as **Expanded** is a flex-widget and it tries to cover entire available space. It then gives constraints to the **Stack** which prevents it from overflow.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I just need to figure out how to align within Expanded then.

Answer (score 0):

You can add symmetric `Padding` to the container to center the `Stack`. Also, add `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center` to the `Stack` to center the widgets inside it(they will only be vertically centered, since they are `Positioned` widgets with `left` parameter provided).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              children: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map((e) => cardWidget(e)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget cardWidget(int index) {
  return Positioned(
    left: index * 50.0,
    child: Card(
      elevation: 10,
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 100,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Note**: adjust the padding amount according to the cards' size and the screen size.

Result:

[image]